# Loop HttpPost requests

Tags: android, http

I need to access data from a webpage using several different post requests. For now I use:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://myurl");  
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "search"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ndc", ndc));  
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

I need to sent this request using different values for the variable ndc. Would looping this lines be a good idea? If so, how to reuse the HttpClient and HttpPost variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the URL needs to stay the same, then you should only change the values that need to sent.

```
for (int i=0; i<ndcArray.length;i++)
{

    if(i==theNumberWhenURLhasToBeChanged)  //adjust this condition based on your    knowledge when the url has to be changed, lets say if i > theNumberWhenURLhasToBeChanged, then change the url...
  {
  httppost = new HttpPost(URLs[theNumberWhenURLhasToBeChanged]);
  }  

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ndc", ndcArray[i]));  
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
}
```

Note that: response will change each time, so bear in mind that you should save the response somewhere. And ndcArray[] can be replaced with any structure you want.

Comment: URL will stay the same for an arbitrary (>1) amount of times, AFTER another URL is initially loaded once.